# 401 Unauthorized while ExchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Hi I have written an standalone Windows Forms application which uses EWS (Exchange Web Services) Managed API to listen to the new mail event on a particular email id. I am using impersonation. This is a part of my code:

```
service = new ExchangeService(SyncSettings.ExchangeServerVersion);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userid, password);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, impersonatedUserId);            
service.Url = new Uri(exchnguri);

FolderId[] folders=new FolderId[1];
folders[0] = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
EventType[] events = new EventType[1];
events[0] = EventType.NewMail; 

subscription = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(folders, new Uri(listenUri), notificationInterval, "", events);
```

On Exchange Server side, I have provided one user account privileges to impersonate another user account.

When I run app in one environment it works fine. But when I run it in another it gives following error:

```
Immediate Stack Trace
===================================================================================
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException : The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications(IEnumerable`1 folderIds, Uri url, Int32 frequency, String watermark, EventType[] eventTypes)
   at com.org.app.Class.startListeningPushNotifications(String listenUri, Int32 notificationInterval) in c:\SW\app\Class.cs:line 156

Inner Exception 1 : Stack Trace
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------     
System.Net.WebException . The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
```

The only difference I observe in two environments is:

In first environment I login owa (Outlook Web Access) using `domainx\userx`, and to send mail to self account (that is, to the account with which I have logged in) I put `userx@domainx.com` in to field

However in second environment I login owa using `domainxdc\userx` (notice 'dc' in `domainxdc`), and send self mail with `userx@domainx.com` in to field. (notice no 'dc' in `domainx.com`)

I dont think that is giving me 401 Unauthorised, since I can login to owa using both impersonating and impersonated account. And I have given impersonating privileges in 2nd environment in exactly the same way as in 1st environment.

So why I am getting 401 Unauthorised ?

We are using Exchange Server 2007 and Windows Server 2008 SP2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try--might work:

```
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

I'm not very clear on why this helps, and in my case, it was going against Exchange Online, not your on-prem E2007.  Might help; can't hurt.  [There was a blog post on this](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/401-erors-in-exchange-online-using-ews.html), but not sure if this will apply to your case.